# php Arrays not giving the correct output

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have created an Array but I am not getting the correct output, I am just wondering where I made error in code below

The Out put should display the name as below

> John
>   James
>   Jonny
>   Jeni

```
<?php 
$multiArray = Array( 
Array("id" => 1, "name" => "John"), 
Array("id" => 2, "name" => "James"), 
Array("id" => 3, "name" => "Jonny"), 
Array("id" => 4, "name" => "Jeni")); 

$tmp = Array(); 
foreach($multArray as &$ma) 
    $tmp[] = &$ma[name]; 

array_multisort($tmp, $multiArray); 

foreach($multiArray as &ma) 
    echo $ma["name"]."<br/>"; 
?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($multiArray as $v) { echo $v['name']."<br />"; }` - like that? You seem to have made it overly complex.

Comment: @qirel thanks for reply, but I stuck with this simple array for long

Comment: ah? What do you mean? Why not following @Qirel suggestion?

Comment: Like I said, that little piece of code in the comment above does *exactly* what you want - you don't need anything else. See this [**live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Sjdtk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to only print the content of the array?

Just do it like this is enough

```
<?php

$multiArray = Array( 
  Array("id" => 1, "name" => "John"), 
  Array("id" => 2, "name" => "James"), 
  Array("id" => 3, "name" => "Jonny"), 
  Array("id" => 4, "name" => "Jeni")
); 

foreach($multiArray as $ma)
{
  echo $ma['name'] . "<br>";
}

?>
```

Also I noticed that in your codes, there is a lot of typo there.

This is your codes after I fixed all the typos:

```
<?php

$multiArray = Array( 
  Array("id" => 1, "name" => "John"), 
  Array("id" => 2, "name" => "James"), 
  Array("id" => 3, "name" => "Jonny"), 
  Array("id" => 4, "name" => "Jeni")
); 

$tmp = Array(); 
foreach($multiArray as $ma) 
    $tmp[] = $ma['name']; 

array_multisort($tmp, $multiArray); 

foreach($multiArray as $ma) 
    echo $ma["name"]."<br/>"; 

?>
```

Output:

```
James
Jeni
John
Jonny
```

Yes the output is different from what you want. this is because you sort the array using array_multisort. read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php